# Change the MacOS MenuBar name of a Chrome Save-Application App

Tags: google-chrome, osx-lion

I created an app for a page (say `reddit.com`) that I visit often using [the Chrome Save as Application shellScript](http://lifehacker.com/5611711/create-application-shortcuts-in-google-chrome-for-mac-with-a-shell-script). When I did so, I had two problems:

1. The `reddit.com` icon was not the icon of my application. This was easily fixed by editing the application icon in Finder.app.
2. The application's name on the menubar was `Chrome` and not `Reddit` (as seen in the screenshot), despite `Reddit` being the name I used while creating the app.

[image]

A little googling showed me [how to change the menubar name of an MacOSX application](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20091113094131870), which tells me to edit the file `InfoPlist.strings`. However, applications created by Chrome don't have that file, and creating it doesn't help either.

I now have no clue what to do, which brings me to posting this question here: How may I change the menubar name of a Chrome-created application on MacOSX

Technical Details:

- Mac OSX 10.7.5 (Lion)
- Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43